# 2 C Errors Incompatible type and expected type

Tags: c

I'm trying to store 3 sets of 5 double numbers from user input. 
I need to store the information in a 3 x 5 array and compute the average of each set of five values.

I can't figure out how to fix two errors.

First error:
   hw9.c:27:2 error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'set_average'
    set_average (array[ROW][COL]);
    ^

Second error:
  hw9.c:8:6: note: expected 'double (*)[5]' but argument is of type      'double'
void set_average(double array[ROW][COL]);

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROW 3
#define COL 5
void set_average(double array[ROW][COL]);
void all_average(double array[ROW][COL]);
void find_largest(double array[ROW][COL]);
int main(void)
{
    double array[ROW][COL];
    int i, j;

    printf("Enter three sets of five double numbers.\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter elements until done.\n");
            printf("Enter %d%d: ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%le", &array[i][j]);
        }   
    printf("Done entering numbers.\n");
    printf("Now it's time to compute the average of each set of five values\n");

    set_average (array[ROW][COL]);

    return 0;
}

void set_average(double array[ROW][COL])
{
    int r;      //row
    int c;
    double sum;
    double avg; //average
        for (r = 0; r < ROW; r++)
            for (c = 0; c < COL; c++)
            {
                sum += array[r][c];
            }
    avg = sum / 5;
    printf("The average is %le\n", avg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling function as

```
set_average (array[ROW][COL]);
```

instead of

```
set_average (array);
```

Function is defined as `void set_average(double array[ROW][COL])` so it expects an array of `ROW`. Each has an array of `COL` items which are doubles. Error was reported because function was called with just one `double` as argument.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass full array to the function

```
set_average (array);
```

As you are passing

```
set_average (array[ROW][COL]);
```

it will send only single value i.e `array[3][5]`

In `set_average` function you have not initialize value of `double sum;` . Initialize `sum` with zero, otherwise you will get wrong Output.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this:
------------------
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROW 3
#define COL 5

void set_average(double array[][COL]);

int main(void)
{
        double array[ROW][COL];
        int i, j;

        printf("Enter three sets of five double numbers.\n");
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                        printf("Enter elements until done.\n");
                        printf("Enter %d%d: ",i+1,j+1);
                        scanf("%le", &array[i][j]);
                }
        printf("Done entering numbers.\n");
        printf("Now it's time to compute the average of each set of five values\n");

        set_average( array );

        return 0;
}

void set_average( double array[ ][5] )
{
        int r;      //row
        int c;
        double sum;
        double avg; //average
        for (r = 0; r < ROW; r++)
                for (c = 0; c < COL; c++)
                {
                        sum += array[r][c];
                }
        avg = sum / 5;
        printf("The average is %le\n", avg);
}
```